# React Native : multiple Navigator navigationBar

Tags: react-native

I'm stuck with React Native.

I have a "Header" navigationBar, but I want to add another navigationBar to my Navigator component.

```
render() {
    let currentRoute = this.props.route
    return (
        <Navigator
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={this.props.route}
            renderScene={this.router.bind(this)}
            navigationBar={<Header />} // << There, how can I simply add another navigationBar ?
         />
    );
}
```

And here's the `<Header/>` component :

```
render() {
    return <Navigator.NavigationBar
        style={styles.navBarContainer}
        navState={this.props.navState}
        routeMapper={routeMapper}
    />
  }
```

**Now, I'm trying to add a `<Footer/>` component, which would render a similar component as `<Header/>`, in order to have 2 persistent navigation bar on my app.**

How to achieve this ?

Comment: How is the arrangment of two bars? vertical? or Just white two bars in on Header Component.

Comment: Well, <Header/> is on top of the screen, <Footer/> on bottom. Both are horizontal navbars.

Comment: I already tried to put my two navbars in the <Header/> component, but I can't figure how I can use style for the right layout (I mean, header on top, content on the middle, footer on bottom) as React Native do not allow all flex properties...

Comment: Maybe you could build your own Footer as part of the component your return from renderScene? At least you can get the layout right that way; but you'd have to build the functionality NavigationBar provides partly yourself..

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this question, and have resolved it. In React Native, it is not supported to add multiple navigationBar. But, if you want to add another "navigationBar", you can add this "navigationBar" as the sibling node of the Navigator, such as:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.scene}>
            <TopStatusBar
                showBackIcon={false}
                centerText={LocalizedStrings.appName} 
                rightIcon={require("../../res/icons/head.png")} 
                onRightPress={this._onHeadPress.bind(this)}
            />

            <Navigator
                initialRoute={ROUTE_STACK[0]}
                renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)}
                configureScene={() => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid}
                navigationBar={
                    this.state.displayBottomTabBar ?
                        <BottomTabBar 
                            ROUTE_STACK={ROUTE_STACK}
                        />
                    :
                        null
                }
                onWillFocus={(route) => {
                    this.presentedRoute = route;
                }}
                sceneStyle={{flex: 1}}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

In the upper code, TopStatusBar is a composite component. It persists across scene transitions, just like the navigatorBar.

Good luck!