# React Navigation error in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I want to use a navigation view and a another view in a same page. How can I do this?

This code run successfully

```js
const MyNav = TabNavigator({
  News: { screen: NewsScreen },
  Videos: { screen: VideosScreen },
  Bands: { screen: BandsScreen },
  Jokes: { screen: JokesScreen },
}, {
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
  animationEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});


export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return <MyNav/>;
  }
}
```

But when I try in this way it returns error

```js
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return(
     <View>
      <MyNav/>
        <View>
          //Something i want
        </View>
     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve this?
[image: Android Emulator Screen when got error]

Answer (score 0):

React Native doesn't support multiple navigations out of the box. You'd need to do it somewhat manually. More info here: [React Native : multiple Navigator navigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647974/react-native-multiple-navigator-navigationbar)

Also note an error here:

```
    <View>
      //Something i want
    </View>
```

When you're inside `render` method, it's not JS code, but JSX. So you can't write comments with `//` as usual. Correct syntax is `{/* Comments */}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want return multiple View in render(), you should group them by array.

Like,

```
return (
 [
  <View key="1">
    <Something/>
  </View>,

  <View key="2">
    <Something/>
  </View>
 ]
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your another view or any other element inside a single parent view. You can only return a single view. Something just like this

```js
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return(
     <View>
            <View>
          <MyNav/>
            </View>
            <View>
               //Something
            </View>            
     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these **steps**

First import react navigation.
Second createStack navigator and then container like createAppContainer.

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
    GetStartedPage: { screen: GetStartedController }, 
    LoginPage: { screen: LoginController }, 

  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'GetStartedPage',
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

Comment: could you please explain where your "steps" does ?

Comment: first import react-navigation and follow below procedures